# How to Use ES6 Template Literals in Freemarker?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, freemarker

I want to use Javascript's ES6 template literal syntax in a Freemarker template. Referring to variables in template literals usually have a syntax of `${name}`.

However the syntax in Freemarker is [remarkably similar](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_var.html) and uses the same syntax to define variables. As a result, when the Freemarker template is parsed, it interprets `${name}` as a freemarker variable and not a Javascript variable, rendering it undefined, thus erroring out.

Does anyone know how one might use ES6 template literal syntax within a Freemarker template?